# Redirection to Stripe Checkout page fail in Rails 7 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In my Rails shopping-cart app I successfully create products with a name and a price. When I proceed to buy the product the redirection fails. From my rails console I can see that the POST request to checkout was successfully accomplished, however, what my browser screen shows me, instead of the Stripe checkout page, is a blank screen with the url of the stripe checkout page. It looks like this: `window.location.href = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_… ‘etc;`. If I copy and paste that url in my browser’s navigation bar I can see the Stripe checkout page with the product information correctly listed.

This is configuration for the checkout functionality:

The views/products/product.html.erb includes a button to checkout:

```
  <div>
    <strong>Price:</strong>
    <%= button_to "Buy now!", checkout_create_path, params: {id: product.id}, remote: true %>
  </div>
```

The button sends to controllers/checkout_controller.rb

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

  def create
      def create
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: product.name
          },
          unit_amount: (product.price * 100).to_i,  # Convert price to cents
        },
        quantity: 1
      }],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: root_url,
      cancel_url: root_url,
    })

  # Render JavaScript response directly
    render js: "window.location.href = '#{@session.url}';"
    end
  end

end
```

Here are my routes:

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'products#index'
  resources :products
  post 'checkout/create', to: 'checkout#create'
end
```

I’ll be mighty thankful for any indications as to how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `@session.url`. Why don't you simply use [Rails redirection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)? You are unnecessary redirecting via JS.